# How to set to other time zone in Cypress while running test?

Tags: timezone, cypress

```
cy.clock()
cy.visit('http://localhost:3333')
cy.get('#search').type('Acme Company')
cy.tick(1000)
// more test code here

// restore the clock
cy.clock().then((clock) => {
  clock.restore()
})
```

How to set timezone in Cypress while running test?
I am in Vietnam, my time zone is GMT+7
While I run test, I want my test run in Timezone GMT+8.

Answer (score -3):

To set a now timestamp you could use:

```
const now = new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 1, 26)).getTime();
cy.clock(now);
```

More info in the documentation: [cy.clock() - Now](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock.html#Now)